# Configurable product in magento is switching to disabled

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Anybody knows why the configurable products are switching disabled after i save them as enabled and all required fields are entered in magento?

Thanks!

Comment: Check for any modules listening to `catalog_product_save_before` event of anything that rewrites `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class

Answer (score 0):

Check your System > Configuration > Inventory for "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock" - it may be that you have inventory quantity that is less than the level set here. I did that and scratched my head for a day!