# How can i change logo of magento in backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can i change the standard logo of magento in the back-end not front-end?
is there an option in the admin for that? or where is the exact `line` in the code where i can change this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't want to override core code here, so let's do this the right way. Doing it properly will mean your change won't get overridden by a possible update carried out later on. It's a bit of a different process to doing this in the back-end than the front-end. But follow these steps and you can do it without touching core code.

Firstly, you're going to need to make a module in order to do it. Make your module, call it whatever you want and in your config.xml add this

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>skin_name</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>skin_name</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Replace `skin_name` with something that makes sense. Then create this folder, replacing `skin_name` again:

> {magento root}/skin/adminhtml/default/skin_name/images

Now, in the images folder you can create a GIF file named `logo.gif` which will override the default one. `logo.gif` is specifically stated in the adminhtml templates so if you want to change the file type/name you'll need to override the template that references the logo too.

### Optional - Changing the file name/type

If you do want to change the image used, create this folder (same deal with replacing `skin_name`):

> {magento root}/app/design/adminhtml/default/skin_name/template/page/

And create `header.phtml` within that folder. Copy the contents of:

> {magento root}/app/design/adminhtml/default/defaut/template/page/header.phtml

and replace:

```
<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/logo.gif') ?>
```

with your chosen image, located in the skin you created earlier like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/my_shiny_new_logo.png') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! can you help me with this too?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418602/configurable-product-in-magento-is-switching-to-disabled thanks!

Comment: To make a Magento module, follow instructions here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Comment: Remember that XML only allows one root element, so <stores> should be located inside root <config> element.

Answer (score 1):

1.Save image at the below location

```
/magento/skin/frontend/default/default/images/<image name>
```

2.Go to admin section

System >Configuration >General > Design > Header > Logo Image Src
put the location as `images/<image name>`

Here change the source address

Comment: This is the front end logo. Op asked for back end logo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update/change logo from Magento backend (without using FTP or without updating any file) then you can do the following:

- Login to your Magento admin
- Edit any static block (`CMS -> Static Blocks`)
- There you will see `Insert Image` button. Click on it.
  [image]
- Upload your logo image there. Suppose, your logo name is `logo.png`. Then, the image path will be `http://your-website.com/media/wysiwyg/logo.png`
- Now, go to `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Header`
- Update `Logo Image Src` to `../../../../../media/wysiwyg/logo.png`. This has to be done because by default Magento fetches image from `skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/images` directory.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

First take Copy of magento's default logo.gif From path `Project_Name\skin\adminhtml\default\default\images\logo.gif` And then save your own image by Replacing logo.gif ,means give same name to Your image too like logo.gif.Its simple.

Answer (score 0):

Logo for admin page is located in `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/`

You can rename/remove the default logo and upload your designed logo, remember to name the file as: **logo.gif**

In case you dont want to replace the original file, you can make change to code in `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml`. Find the line `$this->getSkinUrl('images/logo.gif')` and change logo.gif to you new logo file's name, for example: **newlogo.gif**

Save changes and reload your admin page to see the new logo

Reference source: http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-change-default-magento-logo-in-backend-and-frontend

Answer (score -2):

You can replace the file directly on the server, for magento 1.9.2.1:
`root/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/logo.gif`

Replace that file with your logo.gif, be sure to name it the same.